# How to Count number of rows in a column but excludes NULL values while counting datastage?

Tags: file, etl, datastage

my problem is how to get total number of records in a column but excluding null .

```
source                           target
col1,col2,col3                 col1,col2,col3
a,e,h                           4,3,5
NULL,f,NULL
b,g,i
c,NULL,j
d,NULL,k
NULL,NULL,l
```

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_name != NULL

Comment: or you can use 
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_name NOT NULL

Comment: SELECT count(id) FROM my_table WHERE column_name != NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with the comments to do it in the database might be the easiest way as you have flagged your question with "database".

If you prefer to do it in a DataStage job I suggest to use transformer to set a non null value to 1 and a null to 0 for each column. The result could be then summed in an aggregator stage.

A transformer only solution is possible as well. Also a mix between SQL and a transformer could be an option

Comment: how to complete job in transformer only

Comment: Add a stage variable per column to count, with a logic like: IF IsNull(svCOL1) then svCOL1 ELSE svCOL1 + 1    Add a condition to output ony the LastRow()